# Wikidata mwapi Search multiples terms token

Tags: full-text-search, sparql, wikidata-query-service

Is it possible to search multiple term  using AND operatot with media wiki api ?
I want to perform a full text search with somes token something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
 ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type .   
 VALUES ?term {"token1" AND "token2" AND "token3"}
 SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search ?term; 
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}
```

thanks

Comment: the syntax for `VALUES` would be `VALUES ?term {"book" "bridge" "station"}` but this does only return a union of entities matching any of those terms, not all of them at the same time. If you are really asking for the intersection, i.e. entities that match all terms, I doubt this is possible as it doesn't support Lucene syntax or the like

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for your reply.
I am actually looking to make an intersection like you said. 
My goal is to get wikidata entities whose labels match all the tokens in parameters. For that, i want to build a query who will allow me to retrieve a set of entities given one or more words but I'm still working on it with no result